# Controlling Answer With While Loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I coded a fishing game simulator. I want to control the answer: If answer is not equal to "Y","y","N" or "n", Ask again : Would Like to fish? until until the user presses the correct key. I do not know how to code this algorithm and which line should I put that algorithm.  My code is here:

// --------------------//

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fishinggame {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random dice = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int randomGuess;
    String choice = "Y";
    int score = 0;
    int points = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    
    System.out.println("Let's go fishing!!!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Would you like to fish?");
    System.out.println("Type Y or y for yes");
    System.out.println(" Type N or n for quit");




    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {




        randomGuess = dice.nextInt(6) + 1;  

        if (randomGuess == 1) {
            System.out.println("You caught an old shoe.");
            points += 1;   // If Random Guess is 1 player takes that message and wins 1 point
        }

        if (randomGuess == 2) {
            System.out.println("You caught a huge fish!");
            points += 100;   // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that message and wins 100 points
        }

        if (randomGuess == 3) {
            System.out.println("You caught a leaf ");
            points += 2;   // If Random Guess is 3,player takes that message and wins 2 points
        }

        if (randomGuess == 4) {
            System.out.println("You caught a small fish ");
            points += 50;    // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that massage and wins 50 points
        }

        if (randomGuess == 5) {
            System.out.println("You caught a rock ");
            points += 3;    // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that massage and wins 3 points
        }

        if (randomGuess == 6) {
            System.out.println("You caught a garbage ");
            points += 0;    // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that massage and can not win any point
        }

        System.out.println("Want to try again? Y/N");
        choice = scanner.nextLine();

        counter++;  // This structure counts repeat of game


    }

    if ((choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))) {

        System.out.println("Game Over");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your final score is: " + (points));

        System.out.println("Your game repeat is:" + counter);
        double avarege = (double) points / counter;   // This lane is for counting the average of points
        System.out.printf("Your Average Point Is: %6.2f\n" , avarege);


        if (avarege >= 20) {
            System.out.println("GREAT JOB");
        } else if (avarege >= 10) {
            System.out.println("That is some fine fishing");
        } else {

            System.out.println("Try again in future!");
        }


        System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a _do while_ loop, instead of a _while_ loop.

Comment: Loop while the answer is NOT "N" or "n"; first thing in the loop, if the answer is "Y" or "y", play the game, otherwise, say "Please answer Y or N"; either way, ask "Play again?" as the last thing in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fishinggame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random dice = new Random();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int randomGuess;
        String choice = "Y";
        int score = 0;
        int points = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        
        System.out.println("Let's go fishing!!!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would you like to fish?");
        System.out.println("Type Y or y for yes");
        System.out.println(" Type N or n for quit");

        choice = scanner.next();
        
        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to fish?");
            System.out.println("Type Y or y for yes");
            System.out.println(" Type N or n for quit");
            choice = scanner.next();
        }


        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

            randomGuess = dice.nextInt(6) + 1;  

            if (randomGuess == 1) {
                System.out.println("You caught an old shoe.");
                points += 1;   // If Random Guess is 1 player takes that message and wins 1 point
            }

            if (randomGuess == 2) {
                System.out.println("You caught a huge fish!");
                points += 100;   // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that message and wins 100 points
            }

            if (randomGuess == 3) {
                System.out.println("You caught a leaf ");
                points += 2;   // If Random Guess is 3,player takes that message and wins 2 points
            }

            if (randomGuess == 4) {
                System.out.println("You caught a small fish ");
                points += 50;    // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that massage and wins 50 points
            }

            if (randomGuess == 5) {
                System.out.println("You caught a rock ");
                points += 3;    // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that massage and wins 3 points
            }

            if (randomGuess == 6) {
                System.out.println("You caught a garbage ");
                points += 0;    // If Random Guess is 2,player takes that massage and can not win any point
            }

            System.out.println("Want to try again? Y/N");
            choice = scanner.next();

            counter++;  // This structure counts repeat of game


        }

        if ((choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))) {

            System.out.println("Game Over");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Your final score is: " + (points));

            System.out.println("Your game repeat is:" + counter);
            double avarege = (double) points / counter;   // This lane is for counting the average of points
            System.out.printf("Your Average Point Is: %6.2f\n" , avarege);


            if (avarege >= 20) {
                System.out.println("GREAT JOB");
            } else if (avarege >= 10) {
                System.out.println("That is some fine fishing");
            } else {

                System.out.println("Try again in future!");
            }


            System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
        }
    }
}
```

**The result :**

```
Let's go fishing!!!

Would you like to fish?
Type Y or y for yes
 Type N or n for quit
y
You caught a leaf 
Want to try again? Y/N
y
You caught a rock 
Want to try again? Y/N
y
You caught a small fish 
Want to try again? Y/N
y
You caught a small fish 
Want to try again? Y/N
n
Game Over

Your final score is: 105
Your game repeat is:4
Your Average Point Is:  26,25
GREAT JOB
Thanks for playing!
```

Comment: Sometimes a simple `goto` does wonders, too bad JAVA has no `goto`.

Comment: Thanks @Med Elgarnaoui When I type an another key to consol after typing  "Y",(at the second Y/N question) programm ends. How can I fix that?

Comment: you can do the same test in first while after asking the second question

Comment: It is not working I will open a new title. Thanks a lot.